# As operation 'decimal' * 'decimal' result in a loss of precision but is authorized, why is the operation 'decimal' * 'double' forbidden?

Tags: c#, floating-point

I understand that `decimal` is a number format appropriate for finance and money in general as it has a fixed precision.

So when additionning or substracting two `decimals`, there can never be a loss of precision.

With that in mind, I can understand that the operation '`decimal`' + '`double`' must be forbidden by the compiler, as there can be a loss of precision.

But what happens when you multiply (or divide) two `decimals` ?

Lets consider a simple decimal type, with just 4 digits in total, and 2 digits of precision after the decimal point (from 00.00 to 99.99).

You can define `a = 0.01`

Then `m = a * a = 0.0001`, truncated to `0.00` so there is a loss of precision.

Despite the loss of precision, this operation is considered legal by the compiler.

So we have the following cases in C# :

- `decimal / int` : legal despite loss of precision
- `decimal / decimal` : legal despite loss of precision
- `decimal * decimal` : legal despite loss of precision
- `decimal * double` : illegal

(Of course, you can always override with a cast, but this solution does not feel satisfying to me.)

Is there an other reason I'm not aware of to explain that ?

When dealing with interest rate, or VAT rate, or rates in general, it would seem more logic to me to use a double to store these values, and then be able to use them with a decimal. 
But I have to chose between :

- storing the rate with a `decimal` (overkill).
- storing the rate with a `double` then casting (ugly).

With all that in mind, my question is :

Is there a reason why '`decimal`' * '`double`' is forbidden by the C# compiler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [decimal multiplication (`*`) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.op_multiply%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *only* takes operands of type `decimal`.  However, there is an implicit cast from `int` to `decimal`, so the compiler casts the `int` to a `decimal` for you.

*Techncially*, there is no implicit cast from `decimal` to `double` (or vice-versa, so the compiler can't cast for you; you need to explicitly cast one of the operands.

*Logically*, you need a cast on the last one because the compiler needs to know what the type of the *result* is.  For the first three the type is clear - they all result in a `decimal` because of the implicit cast from `int` to `decimal`.

But what should the result of `decimal` * `double` be?  It could be either `decimal` or `double` depending on your needs.  If you are assigning it to a variable then the compiler *could* infer, but what if it is done inline?  What would the type of `m * a + 1` be?

So you need a cast to tell the compiler what the resulting type is.

> When dealing with interest rate, or VAT rate, or rates in general, it would seem more logic to me to use a double to store these values

Why?  Why would you store an interest rate of 0.10 in a type that *can't store 0.10 exactly*?

`decimal` should be used for financial calculations and other calculations where decimal represnetation needs to be preserved.

`double` should be used for imprecise scientific measurements (temperature, distance) and other calculations where *speed* is more important than the accuracy of the decimal representation.

Comment: Hm, actually this `var s = (double)(12.4m * 23.3d);` is also forbidden, although the result is given. I think it is about tellng the compiler just __how__ to do the calculation.

Comment: @TaW that's more likely due to the subexpression `(12.4m * 23.3d)` failing for the reason given in this answer

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Concerning the rates I'd like to store, it can be things like '1/3 = 0.3333...' that can nether be stored exactly with decimal nor with double.

Comment: @TaW: As a matter of design philosophy, C# does not allow the way in which an expression is used to affect the way in which it is evaluated.  For example, given `Int32 Million = 1000000; Int64 Trillion = Million * Million;`, the result will be -727379968 in an unchecked context, or an OverflowException in a checked context, but will not be the arithmetically-correct 1000000000000 in any case even though it would not be hard for a compiler to recognize that the product is being immediately used as an `Int64` value.